# Access function argument inside function react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am writing a custom react hook for fetching data from an endpoint. This is what the function looks like

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useHttp = async (endpoint, method, data) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [fetchedData, setfetchedData] = useState(null)

    setfetchedData(await fetch.method(endpoint));
    return [isLoading, fetchedData]
}

export default  useHttp;
```

As you can see, I want to do a fetch request to whatever method is passed on to the useHttp hook.  Please someone point me how to do it?

Comment: Is method a string for a given HTTP method? Like "get", "post", "put" etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Use `useEffect` hook to make the HTTP request.

`fetch` function takes an optional second argument which is an object specifying various options for the HTTP request and one of the options is a `method` option. Use this `method` option to specify the request method.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useHttp = async (endpoint, method, data) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [fetchedData, setfetchedData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);

        fetch(endpoint, { method })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
             setLoading(false);
             setfetchedData(data);
          }) 
          .catch(err => {
              setLoading(false);
              console.log(err.message);
          });

    }, []);


    return [isLoading, fetchedData];
}
```

For details on how to specify options for `fetch` function and different options that can be specified, see [using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

If you want to use `async-await` syntax, you can write `useEffect` hook as:

```
useEffect(() => {

    async function makeRequest() {
        setLoading(true);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(endpoint, { method });
            const data = await res.json();
            
            setLoading(false);
            setfetchedData(data);
        
        } catch (error) {
           setLoading(false);
           console.log(err.message);
        }
    }

    makeRequest();

}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass async functions to React Hooks. You have to `useEffect`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useHttp = (endpoint, method, options) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    fetch(endpoint, { method, ...options })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // do something with JSON data
        setFetchedData(json);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // do something with err
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  return [isLoading, fetchedData];
};

export default useHttp;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe this help you:

1- call function:

```
const useHttp = async (url,method,data)=>{
            var options = {
                method:method,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
                }
            };
            if(method==='POST' && data)
               options.body =  JSON.stringify(data);
            const response = await fetch(url, options);
            const rep = await response.json();
            console.log(rep);
            return rep;
};
```

in above code first create your request options and then send it by fetch to end point.

2- use it in compoent like below:

```
setLoading(true);
var rep = await useHttp(...)
setLoading(false);
```